# renderToString returns empty <svg> applied at react barcode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg

I want to create a pdf file out of a HTML element containing a react-barcode. I've been having trouble with it and in my testing I got the following code:

```
  import Barcode from 'react-barcode';
  import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';    

  const barElement = (
    <div>
      <Barcode value={'test'} />
    </div>);

  const stringValue = renderToString(barElement);
  console.log(stringValue);
```

where `stringValue` equals `<div data-reactroot=""><svg></svg></div>`. The Barcode component shows up in my browser fine, but when running `renderToString` it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Don't you need to have your barElement be a proper component in order to render it with renderToString?

Comment: `const stringValue = renderToString(<Barcode value={'test'} />);`
  `console.log(stringValue);` returns the same output if that's what you mean by proper component

Comment: I don't understand what's the current behaviour and what is the expected one

Comment: When inspecting the element in the browser. The barcode component is something along the lines <svg width="178px" height="142px" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 178 142" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ... <svg/>. I assumes that this is what should be returned when using renderToString as well?